# how to delete table row and array index together

Tags: javascript

## Here is my table:

```
delete     Item code      Description     Quantity       Unit price    Discount       Warrenty           Total Price
  *     6935364laptop   laptop          1           600         0       product warrenty          600
  *      6935364desktop  laptop          1           1600        0       warrenty                1600
```

## Here is my array:

```
0: {serial: "6935364laptop", product_name: "laptop", quantity: "1", sell_price: "600", discount: "0", …}

1: {serial: "6935364desktop", product_name: "laptop", quantity: "1", sell_price: "1600", discount: "0", …}
```

## here is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function productsAdd() {  
           var singlProudct = {
            'serial': $("#barcode").val(),
            'product_name': $("#product_name").val(),
            'quantity': $("#quantity").val(),
            'sell_price': $("#sell_price").val(),
            'discount': $("#discount").val(),
            'warrenty': $("#product_warrenty").val(),
            'total_price': $("#total_price").val(),
           }
           allProducts.push(singlProudct);  
        
        if ($("#productTable tbody").length == 0) {
            $("#productTable").append("<tbody></tbody>");
        }        
      
        $("#productTable tbody").append("<tr>" +
            "<td>"+ "<button type='button' onclick='productDelete(this);' class='btn btn-default'>" +
            "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' />" +
            "</button>" +"</td>" +

            "<td name='product_serial[]' id='product_serial' class='product_serial'>"+$("#barcode").val()+"</td>" +
            "<td name='product_name' id='product_name' class='product_name'>"+$("#product_name").val()+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+$("#quantity").val()+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+$("#sell_price").val()+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+$("#discount").val()+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+$("#product_warrenty").val()+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+$("#total_price").val()+"</td>" + "</tr>"            
            );        
        
        var price = parseInt($("#total_price").val());
        var discount = parseInt($("#discount").val());

        $('input[name=barcode').val('');
        total(price,discount); 
    }

function productAddToTable() {
    if ($("#productTable tbody").length == 0) {
        $("#productTable").append("<tbody></tbody>");
    }   
}

function productDelete(ctl) {
    $(ctl).parents("tr").remove();
}
</script>
```

Now i want to delete the table row and array index together i can delete the table row but i can not delete the the array index together.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Separately, your code could be read as a request for people to just write the code for you. Instead, your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @Nick thanks for your comment and i edited with code

Comment: @billah thank you, I have retracted my down vote and close vote.